# Tensorflow MNIST with TFRecord and Dataset low accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I converted the MNIST dataset using the script here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py

Below is the code that I use to read the TFRecord, build the model, and train.

```
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 32
epoch = 20

n_hidden_1 = 256 # 1st layer number of neurons
n_hidden_2 = 256 # 2nd layer number of neurons
num_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
num_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

def parse_func(serialized_data):
    keys_to_features = {'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
                        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_data, keys_to_features)
    prices = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['image_raw'],tf.float32)
    label = tf.cast(parsed_features['label'], tf.int32)
    return prices,tf.one_hot(label - 1, 10)

def input_fn(filenames):
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_func,num_parallel_calls=8)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(50)
    # dataset = dataset.shuffle(2000)

    return dataset.make_initializable_iterator()


weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, num_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
}

# Create model
def neural_net(x):
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Output fully connected layer with a neuron for each class
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

def inference(input):
    input = tf.reshape(input,[-1,784])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=input, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)

    # Logits Layer
    output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense, units=10)
    return output


train_iter = input_fn('train_mnist.tfrecords')
valid_iter = input_fn('validation_mnist.tfrecords')

is_training  = tf.placeholder(shape=[],dtype=tf.bool)

img,labels = tf.cond(is_training,lambda :train_iter.get_next(),lambda :valid_iter.get_next())
# img,labels = train_iter.get_next()

logits = neural_net(img)
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=labels))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss_op)

prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, "float"))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for e in range(epoch):
        epoch_loss = 0
        sess.run(train_iter.initializer)
        count = 0
        while True:
            try:
                count +=1
                _,c = sess.run([train_op,loss_op],feed_dict={is_training:True})
                epoch_loss += c
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break

        print('Epoch', e, ' completed out of ', epoch, ' Epoch loss: ',epoch_loss,' count :',count)

        total_acc = 0
        count = 0
        sess.run(valid_iter.initializer)
        while True:
            try:
                count += 1
                acc = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={is_training:False})
                total_acc += acc
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break

        print('Accuracy: ', total_acc/count,' count ',count)
```

I don't know if I did anything wrong, but the loss and accuracy are not improved after a few epochs. I tested the model above with the traditional way, the feed_dict method. Everything worked fine, I could reach 85% accuracy with that model. Here is the output of the code above

```
Epoch 0  completed out of  20  Epoch loss:  295472940.19140625  count : 1720
Accuracy:  0.5727848101265823  count  158
Epoch 1  completed out of  20  Epoch loss:  2170057598.328125  count : 1720
Accuracy:  0.22231012658227847  count  158
Epoch 2  completed out of  20  Epoch loss:  6578130587.9375  count : 1720
Accuracy:  0.29944620253164556  count  158
Epoch 3  completed out of  20  Epoch loss:  13321823489.0  count : 1720
Accuracy:  0.13310917721518986  count  158
Epoch 4  completed out of  20  Epoch loss:  22460952288.75  count : 1720
Accuracy:  0.20787183544303797  count  158
Epoch 5  completed out of  20  Epoch loss:  34615459125.0  count : 1720
Accuracy:  0.28560126582278483  count  158
Epoch 6  completed out of  20  Epoch loss:  50057282083.0  count : 1720
Accuracy:  0.11748417721518987  count  158
```

I checked the output of the Dataset. Everything look normal and have correct shape. Can somebody point out what I did wrong here ?

**EDIT**
This is the working code, which uses the traditional feed_dict method

```
# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 32
epoch = 5

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 256 # 1st layer number of neurons
n_hidden_2 = 256 # 2nd layer number of neurons
num_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
num_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

# tf Graph input
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_input])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes])

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, num_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
}


# Create model
def neural_net(x):
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    # Hidden fully connected layer with 256 neurons
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    # Output fully connected layer with a neuron for each class
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Construct model
logits = neural_net(X)
loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=Y))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss_op)

prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, "float"))

# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for e in range(epoch):
        epoch_loss = 0
        for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples / BATCH_SIZE)):
            epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
            _, c = sess.run([train_op, loss_op], feed_dict={X: epoch_x, Y: epoch_y})
            epoch_loss += c

        print('Epoch', e, ' completed out of ', epoch, ' Epoch loss: ', epoch_loss)

        # Calculate accuracy for MNIST test images
        print("Testing Accuracy:",sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: mnist.test.images,Y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: I've tried running both sets of code and diff'ing them to see the major differences.  The 2 sets of code are greatly different.  A recommended practice is to provide a minimal example that demonstrates the issue.  Please normalize the two sets of code to be equal other than the issue code which is the data feed.  Second, as the leading answer says, it is very difficult with your tfrecords file.  Please provide the code to create it from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist

Comment: @Panchishin I edited the thread. The main different now is the last part, where I feed data in. Let's me know if there are something unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. In the parse function, I decode the label into one hot vector by using

```
tf.one_hot(label - 1, 10)
```

It should be

```
tf.one_hot(label, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your `tfrecords` files it's difficult to say for sure, but if your data is sorted according to label (i.e. the first 10% of labels are 0s, the second 10% are 1s etc) then failing to shuffle will have a significant effect on your results. 57% accuracy after a single epoch also seems quite surprising (though I've never looked at results at that point), so it's possible your evaluation metric (accuracy) isn't correct (though I can't see anything clearly wrong).

If you haven't visualized your inputs (i.e. the actual images and labels, not just the shape) definitely do that as a first step.

Quite apart from your question, one clear weakness of your code is the lack of non-linearities - a linear layer followed immediately by a linear layer is equivalent to a linear layer. To get more complex behaviour/better results, add a non-linearity e.g. `tf.nn.relu` after each layer apart from the last, e.g.

```
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
```

Finally, `prefetch`ing a large number of dataset elements defeats the purpose of `prefetching`. `1` or `2` is generally enough.

Comment: I visualized the input as you said, everything seems fine. What I couldn't understand is that with the same code and feed_dict method I could reach 85-90% accuracy, but when changing to tfrecord and Dataset. It didn't work anymore and I can't find where the problem is.

Comment: @Thien you say you have working code for Dataset.  Please share a minimum code set that shows that dataset works and that tfrecord does't.  That would greatly help DomJack and others.

Comment: @Panchishin I added the working code which use the feed_dict method. I then converted the MNIST Dataset to TFRecord using the posted link above, and then decode, build model, and train using the first mentioned code. Everything seems to work fine but the loss and accuracy comparing to the feed_dict method is significantly different

Answer (score 0):

@Thien , I downloaded all your files and ran them to generate the tfrecords and then load the tf records.  I inspected your tf records and the image batch returns a shape of 32,194 (which is 14x14 , not 28x28).  I then used matplotlib to look at the images and they don't look like digits at all and do not look like the original mnist data.  Your encoding/decoding into tfrecords is the problem.  Consider writing an encoding function for your tf records, a decoding function for your tf records, and then testing that tfdecode( tfencode( a ) ) == a.

```
    x,y = train_iter.get_next()
    a = sess.run(x)
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.imshow( a[0].reshape(14,14) )
    plt.gray()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for spending time investigating my problem. Did you use my parse_function? I did write a test function as you suggested. The result is that the original and the read tfrecord are equal. Same shape, same value. I can even visualize it.